# How to filter latest objects using nested query in Django

Tags: django

I have the following relation:

```
class Product(foo):
    name = models.CharField()

class Maintenance(foo):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="maintenances")
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
```

I would like to filter all products with the *latest* (only the latest) maintenance object having `start` and `end` attributes in a given date range.

Something like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(maintenances__last__end__gte=today.now(), maintenances__last__end__lte=today.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=30))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `filter` the products on the selected range of dates for maintenances and then take the *lastest* maintenance using `annotation` on `Max`:

```
import datetime as dt

from django.db.models import Max

start_date = dt.datetime.now()
end_date = dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(days=30)

products = Product.objects.filter(maintenances__start__gte=start_date, maintenances__end__lte=end_date)\
                          .annotate(most_recent_maint=Max('maintenances__id'))\
                          .prefetch_related('maintenances')
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it also might make sense to think the other way round: Select the latest `Maintenance` object for every product:

```
# filter for time range
maintenances = Maintenance.objects.filter(
    end__gte=today.now(),
    end__lte=today.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
)
# get latest with distinct product id
maintenances = maintenances.order_by(
    'product_id', '-end'
).distinct('product_id')
# do a `select_related` to get all products in the same query
maintenances = maintenances.select_related('product')
```

Note that passing arguments to `distinct()` only works if you are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: But how do I select the latest maintenance record for every entry I have and make sure the filter is based only on it? If I use `last_` as you provided, it doesn't work. It tries to use it as an attribute.

Comment: Sorry just wrongly copied that... If I understand your question properly it should just filter on `end` of the `Maintenance` objects. Using `order_by` with `distinct` shoud just give you the latest object for every `product_id`.

Comment: That clarifies. Thanks.